# Difference between "to foot the bill" and "to fill the bill"

Tags: differences, idioms

I already knew the expression, "to foot the bill," and there is also, "to fill the bill."  I initially thought this was just a variant, but on closer examination it seems to be an altogether different idiomatic expression.

So what's the difference?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*To foot the bill* is to cover the costs or expenses of something or someone. One of the meanings of the verb *foot* is *to pay for/cover*. Thus, expressions such as *I'll foot it*, *foot the expenses*, *foot the costs*, etc, are also valid.

> **foot** *verb (informal)*: pay (the bill) for something, especially when the bill is considered large or unreasonable.
>
> <sup>— [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1281525#m_en_us1281525)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> - Not to worry. I'll foot the bill.
> - That wedding must have cost an arm and a leg! I wonder how they managed to foot the bill.

*To fill the bill* means *to be suited/fulfill all requirements*. (*Fit* may be more common than *fill* for this expression.)

> **fit** (or **fill**) **the bill**: be suitable for a particular purpose
>
> <sup>— [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1226438?rskey=s3KjP9&result=2#m_en_us1226438)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> - We need someone who is aggressive, motivated and disciplined. Do you fit the bill?
> - He doesn't look like someone who fills the bill.

Comment: I'm a native English speaker and I'd never heard "to fill the bill" meaning to "fit the bill" before! Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

> - **fit (or fill) the bill:** be suitable for a particular purpose (*a partner is an ally or a companion, and you don't seem to fit the bill*).
> - **foot (or pick up) the bill:** (informal) pay the bill, especially when the bill is considered large or unreasonable.

<sup>form the *New Oxford American Dictionary*</sup>

Answer (score 3):

*To foot the bill* is an expression meaning to pay for something.

*To fill the bill* means that something satisfies a need or fits the desired specifications well.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like lots of folks have mentioned how the two senses differ. I think it's worth pointing out that the word "bill" has several meanings in English, which ties into this. Consider these two meanings:

> an itemized statement of money owed
>   for goods shipped or services
>   rendered; "he paid his bill and left";

vs

> a list of particulars (as a playbill
>   or bill of fare)

In the case of "foot the bill", we're talking about a statement of money owed (in many cases, a literal statement on paper).

For "fill the bill" the meaning is more like "matches this set of requirements", which relates to the second meaning of "bill".

Comment: More generally, *bill* covers all sorts of documents, originally sealed (derived from Latin *bulla* in the sense of the seal on a document), then becoming more general, and then splitting into a variety of more specific senses, of which these are two (the legal and legislative senses would probably be the next most common, but there are a great many others).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a native nor fluent speaker of English, but I think 'bill' used in the context means a kind of a printed notice for advertisement. Therefore, 'if sb fills the bill' can be interpreted to mean that he is cut out for the job.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, however the answers before your have sufficiently answered the question. I think your time would be better spent on our [unanswered questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/unanswered).